# postgres query writing to find from my tables which guy exceeded the planned working hour

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

1. employee
2. emplog
   The diagram will show a brief

[image: 1]

I want to find the which employee exceeded the planned working hours which  is represented in employee table by defined_working_hours (TIME).
I have written this query

```
  SELECT em.empid,  em.entrytime, em.exittime, em.break, e.firstname, e.lastname,e.defined_working_hours, SUM(em.exittime - em.entrytime)  AS workedhours, date_part('month',em.entrytime) FROM emplog AS em JOIN employee AS e ON e.empid = em.empid WHERE workedhours > defined_working_hours GROUP BY em.empid, e.defined_working_hours, em.entrytime, em.exittime, em.break, e.firstname, e.lastname, e.empid, date_part('month',em.entrytime) ORDER BY e.empid;
```

But I am getting a error Column "workedhours " does not exist.

I but i know column does not exist when i run the query without "
`WHERE workedhours > defined_working_hours`"

```
SELECT
    em.empid,
    em.entrytime,
    em.exittime,
    em.break,
    e.firstname,
    e.lastname,
    e.defined_working_hours,
    SUM(em.exittime - em.entrytime) AS workedhours,
    date_part('month', em.entrytime)
FROM emplog AS em
JOIN employee AS e ON e.empid = em.empid
GROUP BY
    em.empid,
    e.defined_working_hours,
    em.entrytime,
    em.exittime,
    em.break,
    e.firstname,
    e.lastname,
    e.empid,
    date_part('month', em.entrytime)
ORDER BY e.empid;
```

I am getting a table but the purpose is to find which employee have exceeds their planned working hours more than 1 times per week.
CAN SOME SHED SOME LIGHT WHERE I AM GOING WRONG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `having`:

```
....
having SUM(em.exittime - em.entrytime) > defined_working_hours
ORDER BY e.empid;
```

but your query doesn't look right, I think this is what you want:

```
select * from employee AS e 
join ( 
  select empid,
         to_char(entrytime , 'YYYY mm')) monthyear,
         SUM(exittime - entrytime)  workinghours
  from emplog
  group by empid,
         to_char(entrytime , 'YYYY mm')) 
) em
ON e.empid = em.empid
where  workinghours > defined_working_hours
```

assuming defined_working_hours is monthly bases .

Comment: defined_working_hours  is defined as ' HH12:MI:SS'. I changes the entrytime as '2021-05-01 09:00:00'. I have changed the `to_char(entrytime , 'YYYY mm')) monthyear`, to `to_char(entrytime , 'HH12:MI:SS')) monthyear`, and `to_char(entrytime , 'YYYY mm')) ` to `to_char(entrytime , ' HH12:MI:SS'))`. But it is giving me syntax error at or near ","  in this line `to_char(entrytime , 'YYYY mm')) monthyear`,

Comment: @SimranjeetSingh not sure what are you trying to achieve , abut this answer on its own should answer your question. no need to change anything

Comment: Thanks for your answer i am learning postgresql i am new to it. But your answer  helped me a lot.